# how to catch in PHP oracle grace period message?

Tags: php, oracle, ora-28002

I use an Oracle database in a PHP application.

A user tries to connect to the PHP application. His password has expired, but the grace period for his user's profile isn't null, so he can still connect to the application.

What I would like to do is recognize that this user should change his password and display him a message.

I've tried with `oci_error()`, but it doesn't return anything as there were no failure in connecting to the database with this user.

I would like to catch ORA-28001 (and ORA-28002)

Unfortunately, I can't do any change of structure in the database itself (add extra table or extra field).

Comment: Any other idea / clues / solution ?

Comment: oci_error() can also be used to catch the ORA-28002 message. But error_get_last doesn't seem to work. Using a custom error handler does the trick as well (see Narf's and CJ's comments). Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Narf's answer, this works for me with Oracle 11.2

```
<?php

function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (preg_match('/ORA-28002: [ a-zA-Z]*([0-9])+/', $errstr, $matches)) {
        echo "Your password will expire within ${matches[1]} days\n";
    }
}

set_error_handler("my_error_handler", E_WARNING);

$c = @oci_connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/XE");
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    echo "Connection failed: " . $m['message'] . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Connected OK\n";
    // Prove the connection is valid
    $s = oci_parse($c, "select 'Query is OK' as c from dual");
    oci_execute($s);
    $r = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC);
    echo $r['C'] . "\n";
}

restore_error_handler();

?>
```

Its output for a password in the grace period is:

```
Your password will expire within 1 days
Connected OK
Query is OK
```

Comment: preg_match('/ORA-28002: [ a-zA-Z]*([0-9])+/' : put the "+" into the parenthesis to catch the full number :  preg_match('/ORA-28002: [ a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+)[ ]/', $errstr, $matches)) {

Answer (score 1):

See [OCILogon problem - Oracle password expiry](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3228-ocilogon-problem-oracle-password-expiry) a very similar problem, with a solution. Should work in the current php version. Also very similar to [OCILogon during Grace Period - ORA-28002on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121718/ocilogon-during-grace-period-ora-28002)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any site related to this issue from 2005 and before is irrelevant, as there were some bugs in PHP regarding handling the grace period feature of Oracle DB. Actually, sites from 2005 and before are likely to deal with the bug itself, rather than answering my question.

Comment: Somehow a OCI_ SUCCESS_ WITH_ INFO should be returned. When looking at <http://bugs.php.net/31623> I get the impression that the warning is put somewhere below the carpet, as a solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling warnings when you execute `oci_connect()` and then catching them with a custom error handler(make sure you're not ignoring errors with @ when connecting). This could require you to tweak also the oci extension settings in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to see what was the last warning with error_get_last, but can't exploit any result. oci_connect seems to not give any warning in the case described, as it is a normal scenario/ behaviour itself.